# DRF: How to return name instead of id for permission groups?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a Client model, and a ClientTeamMember model which allows one or more team members to be assigned to each client.  TeamMember in our site is a profile extension of the User account.

In the ClientTeamMember table, we also have a `groups` field, which is the same `Group` model defined in `/django/contrib/auth`.  Its purpose is to be able to assign a group (role) to a TeamMember for a specific client, giving them extra permissions that they don't have for other clients.  Like, for example, making a team member the "Project Manager" for only one client.

Our models:

```
class Client(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ClientTeamMember(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        related_name='client_team_members',
    )
    team_member = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamMember,
        related_name='team_member_clients',
    )
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        blank=True,
        default='',
        related_name='client_groups',
    )
```

We want to return the group names (not just the ids) in the Client serializer.  Like this:

```
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Acme Honey",
            "permission_groups": [
                "Project Manager"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Just as on the User model, Group is a many-to-many field, allowing for multiple groups to be assigned at any level.

Here are the serializers:

```
class GroupNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name']


class ClientGroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groups = GroupNameSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ClientTeamMember
        fields = 'groups'


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    permission_groups = ClientGroupsSerializer(source='client_team_members', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

With the above configuration, this is what it returns:

```
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Acme Honey",
            "permission_groups": [
                {
                    "groups": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

If I remove the `groups = GroupNameSerializer(...)` line, and change fields to `__all__`, I get this:

```
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Acme Honey",
            "permission_groups": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "client": 9,
                    "team_member": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

...so I know it's getting the ClientTeamMember row (which is where the "Project Manager" group is).  I don't understand why it doesn't include the `groups` field in that case, though.

Things I've tried:

- Added level = 1, 2, etc.
- Changed the name of the groups field in `ClientGroupSerializer` and added `source="groups"` to it.
- Changed groups to a ReadOnlyField (and changed its name).
- Overrode the to_representation method in `ClientGroupSerializer`

And the ultimate goal is to return a list of names, instead of `"name": "Project Manager"` as shown in my first "results" example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    permission_groups = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_group_names')

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id','name','permission_groups')

    def get_group_names(self,obj):
        group_name_list = [group.name for group in obj.client_team_members] #assuming group has a name field
        return group_name_list
```

Comment: I thought about ```SerializerMethodField``` fairly early on, but rejected it because I thought I'd have to do a separate query on the ClientTeamMember model - didn't want a separate query on each row of results.  Then I found a thread on SO that had pretty much the same solution your answer offers, but using ```to_representation()``` instead of ```SerializerMethodField```.  I've accepted your answer since it is essentially the same solution.  Thanks for the quick response.